# How to run all tests, including system tests, at once in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

To run tests in Rails 5+, I'd do two separate commands:

```
$ rails test
# Running:
........    
$ rails test:system
# Running:
........
```

How can I run both sets of tests from a single command line request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run all tests, you can list them all:

```
$ rails test:system test:models test:mailers ....
```

And you'll get the correct summarized totals:

```
Finished in 15.824006s, 1.8327 runs/s, 4.2973 assertions/s.
30 runs, 69 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The shortcut is to do:

```
$ rails test:system test
Finished in 14.427353s, 2.0794 runs/s, 4.7826 assertions/s.
30 runs, 69 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Which will do all of your tests since "test" includes all tests, except 'test:system'. One caveat is that if you list 'test' first, it won't run your system tests.

So, this will only run 'test', and not 'test:system'

```
$ rails test test:system
Finished in 0.736070s, 13.5857 runs/s, 23.0956 assertions/s.
10 runs, 17 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 3):

Running "$ rails --tasks" we find this new command (I'm using rails 6.1.3.2):

```
$ rails test:all   # Runs all tests, including system tests
```